# Laravel Polymorphic Relationship with Custom Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.6

I have the following

```php
    Schema::create('bursary_providers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('bursary_provider',64);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('bursary_provider_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('bursary_provider_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('bursary_provider_id')->references('id')->on('bursary_providers')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('contact_name', 32);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

1) Yes, I know this doesnt follow the typical convention where one stores a 'type'. I am doing it as above for referential integrity.

2) I am storing it in a custom named pivot table because it just makes more sense to me. Laravels pivot table requirements are that its alphabetical but lets keep it like this as I want the naming to be parent_child

Now, how do I setup my model? By my understanding, this case would be a morphMany (there are other parents other than 'bursary_providers' - left out just to avoid confusion). So I would use the following in my BursaryProvider model:

```php
public function contacts() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Contact');
}
```

And the following in my Contacts Model:

```php
public function bursary_provider () {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

How do I alter the above so that they connect properly using the **bursary_providers.id** / **contacts.id** and the pivot table **bursary_provider_contacts** (with *bursary_provider_id* and *contact_id*)?

// Edit
For clarity, another 'parent' other than bursary_providers (bursary_providers can have many contacts; bursary_administrators can have many contacts; contacts belong to one):

```php
    Schema::create('bursary_administrators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('bursary_administrator',64);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('bursary_provider_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('bursary_administrator_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('bursary_administrator_id')->references('id')->on('bursary_administrators')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: I don't see the morph relationship anywhere. Everything looks like a many to many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. On the other hand, I don't think you need to add ->index() to the ->increments() columns.

Comment: morphMany ? Where you getting this from??

Comment: can you include  the "other parents" other than `bursary_providers` so we can determine the type of relationship, because as it is now its `many-to-many` with only these tables involved. Additionally, remove `unsigned()->index()`  on all the `id`s because its the primary key.

Comment: updated question with further details as comments above requested. On another note, (1) why would I remove unsigned? i have no use for negative id's (2) why remove index if I want to index the id?

Comment: My understanding of "many-to-many" also means that many one specific contact can belong to many bursary_providers. That is not the case, one specific contact can only belong to one bursary_provider. One bursary_provider can have many contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to follow Laravel naming conventions, in my opinion I'd strongly advise against it. Mainly because if you follow the conventions it works and secondly you're just making more work for yourself!

So what you need to do is pass your desired table name as a second parameter on the relationship. I can't understand why you're using morphMany, you should be using belongsToMany

**Example**

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(App::Contact, 'bursary_provider_contacts');
}

public function bursary_provider () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bursary provider::class, 'bursary_provider_contacts');
}
```

**Edit**

Just as a foot note about relationship types

Let's say you have a product model, an order model, and an invoice model.

Now the products could belong to the order, they can also belong to the invoice.

This doesn't justify a polymorphic relationship, this simple means you'd have the following tables:

products
orders
invoices
order_product
invoice_product

Now an example of a polymorphic, Laravel use this same example because it's common.

Say you have a post model, video model and a comment model.

Now the posts model could have comments

And the video model could have comments.

So Instead of building a PostComment and VideoComment model you can simple build a Comment model and by defining polymorphic relationships the comments for both models will be stored associated to the desired model.

I don't want to be condescending but seriously check out the Laravel documents they're so helpful.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations
```

Comment: updated question with further details as comments above requested

Comment: Still not a polymorphic relationship

Comment: Clearly my understanding of relationships isnt right, your belongsToMany solution _appears_ to have done the trick.

Comment: No worries! I used to do the same thing!

Comment: On a side note, short of stipulating the table on the relationship definition; where else would I be creating more work for myself (now or down the line)?

Comment: When you use the conventional naming terms i.e. products table, orders table and then an order_products table, with a product_id and an order_id column, laravel instantly maps the relationship. with a simple $this->belongsToMany(Product::class); When you start using different names you then have to map it manually by declaring the table name and in odd cases the column. It may seem like a menial thing but say you have to do that on 50 different relationships, you incur loads of extra work time. Also Laravel exists so you dont have to do all this boring nonsense.

Comment: Also so much easier to maintain because what may seem like a good idea now, may make no sense to you in a few months/years.